# Validation on fieldset. The fieldset is inside the form and has inputs outside

Tags: html, xhtml, forms, fieldset

```
<form id="youtube-form" method="post" action="">

  <label for="searchField" id="label-youtube-id">YouTube ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="searchField" name="videoid" class="search-field" />

  <fieldset id="outputFieldset">
    <legend>Output format:</legend>
        <label for="flv">FLV</label>
        <input type="radio" id="flv" name="format" class="radio-button" value="flv" />

        <label for="avi">AVI</label>
        <input type="radio" id="avi" name="format" class="radio-button" value="avi" />

        <label for="mp3">MP3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mp3" name="format" class="radio-button" value="mp3" />
  </fieldset>

  <input id="youtube-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

What is wrong with this code? I seem to get an error when I validate. (three of them too)

> Line 21, Column 49: document type does
>   not allow element "label" here;
>   missing one of "ins", "del", "h1",
>   "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "p",
>   "div", "address", "fieldset" start-tag

Is it because I need to add more fieldsets, or is it something else I have done wrong?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` and `label` elements are not allowed as child elements to `form` elements.

`ins`, `del`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `p`, `div`, `address`, `fieldset` are allowed as child elements and are also allowed to have `input` and `label` elements as their children (although most are not semantically appropriate).

Comment: Thank you :) Now I understand the problem. But why do you see so many guides on the internet omitting the fieldset completely?

Comment: Inputs and labels are allowed as child elements of forms in Transitional versions of HTML. We are far past the transitional period now.

Answer (score 2):

Labels and inputs should be inside the fieldset. Or create a second/third filedset to enclose them separately.

eg:

```
<form id="youtube-form" method="post" action="">


 <fieldset id="youtube">
  <label for="searchField" id="label-youtube-id">YouTube ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="searchField" name="videoid" class="search-field" />
 </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="outputFieldset">
    <legend>Output format:</legend>
        <label for="flv">FLV</label>
        <input type="radio" id="flv" name="format" class="radio-button" value="flv" />

        <label for="avi">AVI</label>
        <input type="radio" id="avi" name="format" class="radio-button" value="avi" />

        <label for="mp3">MP3</label>
        <input type="radio" id="mp3" name="format" class="radio-button" value="mp3" />
  </fieldset>

 <fieldset id="submit">
  <input id="youtube-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for provided the proper code for me to use. I have learned from this.